# differences between cpu and gpu (graphics)

Tags: graphics, gpu, cpu

I'm trying to understand some things better in my computer graphics class. What are the main differences between CPU and GPU? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

OK the main difference is that a GPU has very specialized structure to handle just graphics. You could think of the CPU as being a unit that just follows instruction and uses the Arithemetic and Logic unit to perform computations with data coming in and going out; either sequentially or in a parallel way. But a GPU has general purpose hardware which has different hardware units specially wired to perform several hugely complex intensive tasks which if performed by a CPU would take a long time. I think the Wikipedia article on GPU should explain more clearly.